# How to allow a class to be created by another without using 'friend' but allow inheritence?

Tags: c++, inheritance, components, friend

I have three classes in total for my game engine, an abstract IComponent class in which all components inherit from it, a component class (for this example I will use RenderComponent), and a ComponentManager. I want the ComponentManager class to be able to use the constructor of RenderComponent, but I don't want any other classes to create an instance of RenderComponent, but I don't want to use 'friend' since I want customer user components to inherit from IComponent and automatically be used in the ComponentManager without being allowed to instantiate their own. The code example shows vaguely the behavior I want to occur:

```
class GameObject;

class IComponent
{
    private:
        IComponent() { }
        ~IComponent() { }
    public:
        GameObject* Parent;
}

class RenderComponent : IComponent
{
    public:
        RenderComponent() { }
        ~RenderComponent() { }
}

class ComponentManager
{
    public:
        ComponentManager() { }
        ~ComponentManager() { }

        // normally this would be a template function, but for the sake of this example I will directly use RenderComponent
        RenderComponent* CreateComponent()
        {
            // this would not throw a compiler error
            return new RenderComponent();
        }
}

int main()
{
    ComponentManager manager;

    // even though the constructor of RenderComponent is public, this would throw an error
    RenderComponent* render = new RenderComponent();

    // this however would work perfectly fine
    RenderComponent* render = manager.CreateComponent();

}
```

To reiterate, I want it so that there is minimal user effort to creating components. The other option of course is to have the constructor for both public but have it so that although you can create a component wherever you want, it will be useless.

Comment: You can do that using the factory pattern but not the way you are attempting to do.

Comment: I don't know how to not use 'friend' when making a factory pattern though, although I would switch to it if it solved my issue.

Comment: Your explanation for why you don't want to use `friend` doesn't really make sense. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I just don't want the user to have to do `friend class ComponentManager` every time they make their own component. I could just make the constructor/destructor public, but I also want to restrict the user's ability to instantiate components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to thank [R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434551/r-sahu) for providing his answer, but the in his example would still allow the user to do what I wanted to avoid in the first place, randomly be able to create an instance of a component:

```
IComponent* component = new RenderComponent();
```

And now I realize that what I wanted is impossible, there is no way to restrict access of the constructor/destructor to the user without it also restricting access to the ComponentManager. So either my implementation is wrong or incomplete (which is unlikely but possible) or I'm asking for something that is illogical (the most likely answer).

So instead I just opted for having everything public, and just making randomly created components useless, and in the documentation of my engine I will describe that you have to use GameObject::AddComponent() in order to create and use components.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the factory design pattern, `ComponentManager` does not need to know anything about the concrete sub-types of `IComponent`. There is no need for it to be declared as a friend of the sub-types. It can simply use a *factory* to construct objects.

Creators of sub-types of `IComponent` will need to register a way for instances of the sub-type to be constructed. They register a function or a class with the factory that can construct an instance of the class.

#### An Example Program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

class GameObject;

class IComponent
{
   // Make sure that sub-classes of IComponent can use the constructor
   // and the destructor.
   protected:
      IComponent() { }
      ~IComponent() { }

   public:
      GameObject* Parent;
};

// Define a function type that can construct a Component.
using ComponentConstructor = IComponent*  (*)();

// Define the interface for the factory.
class ComponentFactory
{
   public:

      // A type alias for simpler coding.
      using ConstructorMap = std::map<std::string, ComponentConstructor>;

      // Allow creators of sub-classes of IComponent to register a
      // function that can be used to construct the sub-type.
      static void registerComponentConstructor(std::string const& componentType,
                                               ComponentConstructor constructor);

      // Construct a Component by providing a name corresponding
      // to the derived sub-type of IComponent.
      static IComponent* constructComponent(std::string const& componentType);

   private:

      // Private function that maintains a map of
      // constructors.
      static ConstructorMap& getConstructrMap();
};

// -----------------------------------------------------
// BEGIN implementation of ComponentFactory.
// It can, obviously, be in a .cpp file of its own.
void ComponentFactory::registerComponentConstructor(std::string const& componentType,
                                                    ComponentConstructor constructor)
{
   getConstructrMap()[componentType] = constructor;
}

IComponent* ComponentFactory::constructComponent(std::string const& componentType)
{
   ConstructorMap& constructorMap = getConstructrMap();
   ConstructorMap::iterator iter = constructorMap.find(componentType);
   if ( iter != constructorMap.end() )
   {
      return iter->second();
   }
   else
   {
      return nullptr;
   }
}

ComponentFactory::ConstructorMap& ComponentFactory::getConstructrMap()
{
   static ConstructorMap theMap;
   return theMap;
}

// END implementation of ComponentFactory.
// -----------------------------------------------------

// ComponentManager can use ComponentFactory to 
// construct Components.
class ComponentManager
{
   public:
      ComponentManager() { }
      ~ComponentManager() { }

      IComponent* CreateComponent(std::string const& componentType)
      {
         return ComponentFactory::constructComponent(componentType);
      }
};

// Test code.
// Construct IComponents by using appropriate names.
int main()
{
   ComponentManager m;
   IComponent* ic1 = m.CreateComponent("RenderComponent");
   if ( ic1 == nullptr )
   {
      std::cout << "Unable to construct a Component of type RenderComponent.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Successfully constructed a Component of type RenderComponent.\n";
   }

   IComponent* ic2 = m.CreateComponent("AnotherTypeOfComponent");
   if ( ic2 == nullptr )
   {
      std::cout << "Unable to construct a Component of type AnotherTypeOfComponent.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Successfully constructed a Component of type AnotherTypeOfComponent.\n";
   }

   IComponent* ic3 = m.CreateComponent("FooComponent");
   if ( ic3 == nullptr )
   {
      std::cout << "Unable to construct a Component of type FooComponent.\n";
   }
   else
   {
      std::cout << "Successfully constructed a Component of type FooComponent.\n";
   }
}

// Client components.
// Without these, no Component can be constructed.

namespace Module1
{
   class RenderComponent : IComponent
   {
      public:
         RenderComponent() { }
         ~RenderComponent() { }

         static IComponent* constructComponent()
         {
            return new RenderComponent();
         }

         struct Initer
         {
            Initer()
            {
               ComponentFactory::registerComponentConstructor("RenderComponent",
                                                              RenderComponent::constructComponent);
            }
         };
   };

   // The constructor makes sure that
   // RenderComponent::constructComponent() is
   // registered as the function to be called to
   // construct objects of type RenderComponent when
   // the name "RenderComponent" is used.
   // 
   // A different method may be used for the purpose but
   // this seems like a straight forward method to do that.
   static RenderComponent::Initer initer;

}

namespace Module2
{
   class AnotherTypeOfComponent : IComponent
   {
      public:
         AnotherTypeOfComponent() { }
         ~AnotherTypeOfComponent() { }

         static IComponent* constructComponent()
         {
            return new AnotherTypeOfComponent();
         }

         struct Initer
         {
            Initer()
            {
               ComponentFactory::registerComponentConstructor("AnotherTypeOfComponent",
                                                              AnotherTypeOfComponent::constructComponent);
            }
         };
   };

   // The constructor makes sure that
   // AnotherTypeOfComponent::constructComponent() is
   // registered as the function to be called to
   // construct objects of type AnotherTypeOfComponent when
   // the name "AnotherTypeOfComponent" is used.
   static AnotherTypeOfComponent::Initer initer;
}
```

#### Output

```
Successfully constructed a Component of type RenderComponent.
Successfully constructed a Component of type AnotherTypeOfComponent.
Unable to construct a Component of type FooComponent.
```

Comment: I'll test this out with my code and see if it works.